# How do I map one column to multiple columns in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark data frame that looks like this:

```
df.show()
+---+
|dim|
+---+
|1x1|
|0x0|
|1x0|
+---+
```

The data type in `dim` is `str`. Now I want to separate `dim` into 2 column, and have something like this:

```
df.show()
+---+----+----+
|dim|dim1|dim2|
+---+----+----+
|1x1|   1|   1|
|0x0|   0|   0|
|1x0|   1|   0|
+---+----+----+
```

I know that if I were to operate on a single string I'd just use the `split()` method in python: `"1x1".split("x")`, but how do I simultaneously create multiple columns as a result of one column mapped through a split function?

Comment: Please use the search option before posting the Q. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46835882/pyspark-split-columns

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @Frank! I wasn't searching with the right keywords...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import split
df_temp = df.withColumn("dim1", split("dim", "x")[0])
df_new = df_temp.withColumn("dim2", split("dim", "x")[1])
df_new.show()
```

Or you can chain these together in one call:

```
df_new = df.withColumn("dim1", split("dim", "x")[0])\
    .withColumn("dim2", split("dim", "x")[1])
```

Comment: Apologies yes I meant `df_new.show()`. Will edit.

Comment: I got an error from the first line: "TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable."

Comment: It seems that `df.dim.split("x")` is causing problems

Comment: @GraceO'Halloran  this syntax is incorrect (I don't know how I missed it the first time). You need to call `pyspark.sql.functions.split()`: `df.withColumn("dim1", f.split("dim", "x")[0])` etc where `f` is `pyspark.sql.functions`

Comment: @pault pointed out that I needed to use `pyspark.sql.functions.split()` and that solved this problem. If we change the first line to `df_temp = df.withColumn("dim1", split(df.dim, "x")[0])` it would work.

Comment: Ah fab - thank you @pault

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `rdd` and `map()`:

```
df = df.rdd.map(lambda row: (row['dim'],) + tuple(row['dim'].split('x')))\
    .toDF(["dim", "dim1", "dim2"])
df.show()
#+---+----+----+
#|dim|dim1|dim2|
#+---+----+----+
#|1x1|   1|   1|
#|0x0|   0|   0|
#|1x0|   1|   0|
#+---+----+----+
```

And here is an adaptation of [@Grace O'Halloran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4139097/grace-ohalloran)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49373575/5858851) using [`pyspark.sql.functions.split()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.split) in a loop instead of enumerating the possibilities (useful if you have a large number of dimensions):

```
ndim = 2
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
for d in range(ndim):
    df = df.withColumn('dim{}'.format(d+1), f.split('dim', 'x')[d])
```