# Split PySpark dataframe column at the dot

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I have tried the below in Pandas and it works. I wondered how I might do it in PySpark?

The input is

```
news.bbc.co.uk
```

it should split it at the '.' and hence index should equal:

```
[['news', 'bbc', 'co', 'uk'], ['next', 'domain', 'name']]

index = df2.domain.str.split('.').tolist()
```

Does anyone know how I'd do this in spark rather than pandas?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split Contents of String column in PySpark Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41283478/split-contents-of-string-column-in-pyspark-dataframe) and [Splitting a column in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48790246/splitting-a-column-in-pyspark) and [Pyspark Split Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46835882/pyspark-split-columns?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pyspark.sql.functions.split`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.split) to split `str`.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = df.withColumn('col_name', F.split(F.col('col_name'), '.'))
```

Answer (score 17):

Using '.' works in a different way. Using it with escape character '\' actually worked.

```
df = df.withColumn('col_name', F.split(F.col('col_name'), '\.'))
```

Comment: still doesnt work form me, it's giving result like [, , , , , ] when I tried to split the string = 'a.b.c'

Comment: Which version of python did you use? @AswinKs

Comment: With Python 3.5.2 (databricks runtime 5.5 LTS), works with `df.withColumn('col_name', F.split(F.col('col_name'), '[\.]'))`. I guess it is some kind of bug, or me not understanding correctly regular expressions (highly possible.)

Comment: '[\.]' instead if '\.' worked for me @AswinKs

Answer (score 0):

```
df.select(split("col_name", '[\.]'))
```

or

```
df.selectExpr("split(col_name, '[\.]')")
```